# How to select on existing (or non existing) key/value pair in sub structure

Tags: filter, jq

I have the following (simplified) JSON object:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 2584,
        "customProperties": [
          {
            "name": "jira.assetid",
            "value": "1"
          },
          {
            "name": "system.categories",
            "value": "collector"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2603,
        "customProperties": [
          {
            "name": "system.categories",
            "value": "snmp"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2703,
        "customProperties": [
          {
            "name": "jira.assetid",
            "value": "5"
          },
          {
            "name": "system.categories",
            "value": "snmpTCPUDP,Netsnmp,snmpHR,snmp"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I filter all devices which have (or don't have) a "jira.assetid"?

My goal is to get 2 outputs:

No jira.assetid present:  id, jira.assetid

Yes jira.assetid present:  only id

The following gives me the id's of the devices with a jira.assetid, but how to get the assetid also on the output:

```bash
cat devices.txt | jq -r '.data.items[]
                | select(.customProperties[].name == "jira.assetid")
                |.id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are at least two possible solutions, one first building a list of all id + assetid combinations, the other converts the custom properties to an object first.

Streaming solution:

```
.data.items[]
| {
    id,
    assetId: (.customProperties[] | select(.name == "jira.assetid").value)
}
```

Object solution:

```
.data.items[]
| {
    id,
    assetId: (.customProperties | from_entries."jira.assetid")
}
| select(.assetId)
```

Or using the special `empty` filter instead of selecting a second time:

```
.data.items[]
| {
    id,
    assetId: (.customProperties | from_entries."jira.assetid" // empty)
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "id": 2584,
  "assetId": "1"
}
{
  "id": 2703,
  "assetId": "5"
}
```

---

To get only the elements without an assetid:

```
.data.items[]
| select(any(.customProperties[]; .name == "jira.assetid") | not)
| { id }
```

or by building an object first, which I find slightly easier to grok:

```
.data.items[]
| select(.customProperties | from_entries | has("jira.assetid") | not)
| { id }
```

Output:

```json
{
  "id": 2603
}
```

To get only the ids for items without asset id:

```
.data.items[]
| select(.customProperties | from_entries | has("jira.assetid") | not)
| .id
```

Output:

```
2603
```

Comment: Knittl,

this works fine for getting every device which has a jira.assetid. Thanks a lot

What would be the approach to get the devices where this name/valuepait is non-existing? Of course I can do a diff with the full list, butbeing able to do this in 1 go would be preferred.

Comment: @JeroenG I have updated my answer to include two programs to show only the ids without assetid.